# Navigation is not working on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am developing a web app in asp.net web forms with master page. Application is running in debug mode in my localhost. When I click on the link in menu it navigates but when I again click on any link in menu it gives me the resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a location issue. Make sure you are calling the file in the right directory.

If you are Redirecting from the Server-Side then use

```
Response.Redirect("~/MyFolder/MyPage.aspx");
```

or from the Client-Side

```
href="../MyFolder/MyPage.aspx"
```

This is assuming that you have the MasterPage in its own folder in the project.

Answer (score 0):

u should try giving the links using ResolveClientUrl,I had the same problem..!!

```
 <a href='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Folder/Page.aspx") %>'>LinkName</a>
```